# Java - Como puedo hacer que me remplace los valores y me elimine los anteriores de un arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, replace, formato-condicional, apache-netbeans

Estoy tratando de remplazar los valores que ingrese antes, buscandolo en este caso por la cedula y tomando la poscision, pero al entrar al if, no me remplaza solo crea otra linea con el texto nuevo, y al finalizar no me pide un nuevo registro si no que continua pidiendo los otros datos.

Saben alguna forma para poder remplazar los valores y que se eliminen los anteriores o alguna otra forma para que se cumpla lo que le pido al programa?

-Adjunto el codigo para que se pueda apreciar lo que quiero hacer:

```
package com.mycompany.tercerreto;

public class reto3 {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        CalculosIndiceMasaCorporal calcularImcYEtapa = new CalculosIndiceMasaCorporal();

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        DecimalFormatSymbols separadoresPersonalizados = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        separadoresPersonalizados.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0", separadoresPersonalizados);
        List cedulas = new ArrayList();       
        List nombres = new ArrayList();
        List apellidos = new ArrayList();
        List edades = new ArrayList();
        List pesos = new ArrayList();
        List tallas = new ArrayList();
        List tipoPeso = new ArrayList();
        List etapa = new ArrayList();
        List imcS = new ArrayList();
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            int cedula = leer.nextInt();
            String stringCedula = String.valueOf(cedula);
            int numeroC = Integer.parseInt(stringCedula);
            String numCedula = String.valueOf(cedula);
            int longitudCedula = numCedula.length();

            for (int l = 0; l < cedulas.size(); l++) {
                if (cedulas.contains(stringCedula)) {
                    System.out.println("Entraste a remplazar");
                    cedulas.set(l, stringCedula);
                    String nombre = leer.next();
                    nombres.set(l, nombre);
                    String apellido = leer.next();
                    apellidos.set(l, apellido);
                    int edad = leer.nextInt();
                    edades.set(l, edad);
                    for (j = 0; j < cedulas.size(); j++) {
                        float peso = leer.nextFloat();
                        pesos.set(l, peso);
                        float talla = leer.nextFloat();
                        tallas.set(l, talla);
                        float imc = peso / (talla * talla);
                        imcS.set(l, imc);
                        tipoPeso.set(l, calcularImcYEtapa.calcularClase(imc));
                        etapa.set(l, calcularImcYEtapa.calcularEtapa(edad, imc));
                        System.out.println("Sales de los for");                                                
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("False");
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (cedula <= 0) {
                for (k = 0; k <= 1; k++) {
                    System.out.println("REG-" + (k + 1) + " -> " + "{'cédula': " + cedulas.get(k) + "," + "'apellido': " + apellidos.get(k) + "," + "'nombre': " + nombres.get(k) + "," + "'edad': " + edades.get(k) + "," + "'clase': " + tipoPeso.get(k) + "," + "'imc': " + df.format(imcS.get(k)) + "," + "'etapa': " + etapa.get(k) + "}");
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (longitudCedula < 7 || longitudCedula > 10) {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Aqui uno");
        
            cedulas.add(stringCedula);
            String nombre = leer.next();
            nombres.add(nombre);
            String apellido = leer.next();
            apellidos.add(apellido);
            int edad = leer.nextInt();
            edades.add(edad);
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                float peso = leer.nextFloat();
                pesos.add(peso);
                float talla = leer.nextFloat();
                tallas.add(talla);
                float imc = peso / (talla * talla);
                imcS.add(imc);
                tipoPeso.add(calcularImcYEtapa.calcularClase(imc));
                etapa.add(calcularImcYEtapa.calcularEtapa(edad, imc));
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("REG-" + (k + 1) + " -> " + "{'cédula': " + cedulas.get(k) + "," + "'apellido': " + apellidos.get(k) + "," + "'nombre': " + nombres.get(k) + "," + "'edad': " + edades.get(k) + "," + "'clase': " + tipoPeso.get(k) + "," + "'imc': " + df.format(imcS.get(k)) + "," + "'etapa': " + etapa.get(k) + "}");
        }
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            System.out.println("REG-" + (k + 1) + " -> " + "{'cédula': " + cedulas.get(k) + "," + "'apellido': " + apellidos.get(k) + "," + "'nombre': " + nombres.get(k) + "," + "'edad': " + edades.get(k) + "," + "'clase': " + tipoPeso.get(k) + "," + "'imc': " + df.format(imcS.get(k)) + "," + "'etapa': " + etapa.get(k) + "}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que quieres realizar pero revisando las primeras líneas de tu código veo varios errores comenzando con el List que declaras como objeto, luego estas queriendo buscar un String en una lista de objetos vacíos

Comment: Tienes muchas lecturas de teclado, y empiezas por un Int, recuerda que cuando intruduces un valor numérico por teclado, luego no puedes recoger un string, pues el búffer recogerá el intro y no lo que hayas tecleado. Para ello tienes que limpiar ese búffer con leer.nextLine();. Por otro lado, para capturar un string, mejor nextLine() que next().

Comment: @Joshin Pido disculpa por eso, apenas inicio en esto de la programacion, Lo que quiero hacer es, primero me piden ingresar unos datos, luego valido segun la "cedula" si ya se encuentra ese dato creado, si lo está debo remplazarlo, ya que no puedo tener 2 datos iguales (remplazar nombre,apellido, peso, talla etc), pero en caso que no este ese dato siga pidiendo el resto normal, mi propuesta fue tener varias listas y remplazar los valores con posicion en caso ya se encuentre repetido, pero cuando encuentra un dato que ya estaba, escribe un nuevo "formulario" con los datos

Comment: @Cesar puedes crear una Clase donde los atributos sean todas las listas que estas declarando, si eso responde a tu pregunta me escribes para darte un ejemplo de como hacerlo si aún no sabes, o ¿Cuál es la razón de crear varias listas?

Comment: @Joshin la cantidad de listas es para almacenar los datos independientemente, ya que la actividad me la califica un VPL y me pide mostrar la información con unos caracteres y símbolos en especial, gracias a un comentario logré hacer que remplazara pero no logré solucionar el salto, cuando esté de nuevo con el código que lo pueda subir actualizaré lo que hice, muchas gracias por la ayuda hasta ahora